# Addition recursively

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

How would you recursively add numbers? Just in terms of pseudocode how would one approach such a problem in the most efficient run time

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? How are you representing the numbers? In most programming languages, addition of numbers is a primitive operation.

Answer (score 2):

As a simple rule of recursion, any function can be computed using a recursive routine if :
1. The function can be expressed in its own form.
2. There exists a termination step, the point at which f(x) is known for a particular ‘x’.

Therefore to write a recursive program for addition of 2 numbers, we have to express addition in a recursive form using the above 2 rules :
1. add(m,n) = add(m,n-1)+1 (recursive defination of addition).
2. if n=0, return m (termination step).
Using these 2 rules, the recursive program of addition can be coded very easily as shown :

add(int m,int n)
    { if(n==0)
       return m;
      y=add(m,n-1)+1;
      return y;
    }